# Anomaly detection and performance metrics across two groups

Tags: classification, anomaly-detection

I have one-year-long temperature data collected daily from two groups of computers. Group-1 has 50 computers and Group-2 has 100 computers. Group-1 is a set of defective computers and their temperature goes way up during summer. Group-2 is a set of good computers and their temperature goes up in summer but not as much as other group.

I want to show that defective computers have anomalous temperatures in summer compared to good computers and report each day as anomalous or not. To address this, I came up with the following questions and solution but not sure whether it is the correct way..

`questions`

1. Identify days that have higher/anomalous temperatures in summer.
2. Classify if the anomalous day in summer belongs to a good or defective computer.
3. Performance metrics for problems 1 and 2

`solutions`

1. solution - Use non-summer days data as baseline/training and summer data as test data. Apply an anomaly detection method (autoencoder for ex:) to Group-1 and identify anomalous days with high temp in summer. Do the same as above with Group-2
2. solution - Built a classifier using anomalous daily data points from Group-1 and Group-2 to identify whether the data point is from a good or defective computer.
3. solution - For probelm-1, sensitivity and specificity using training and test data for each computer. For problem-2, Sn and Sp using all anomalous data from Group1 and Group2.

Comment: Are group 1 and group 2 known in advance?

Comment: yes. all the data is present.